# Multiple conditions on single checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to have a single checkbox in a form but i need to implement multiple scenarios but not sure if this is possible using a single checkbox or if i need radio buttons . Please advise

1. box shown and checked: Accepted / yes
2. (hidden)Box shown and not checked: Declined / no
3. Box not shown: Not Shown / blank

Comment: What do you mean by "possible"? In what sense?

Comment: in the sense if the requirements 1/2/3 can be met using a single checkbox .The reason i ask is a single checkbox can hold only one value and if there is a way i can alter the value in Jquery dynamically still satisfying all the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> not sure if this is possible using a single checkbox
>
> 1. box shown and checked: Accepted / yes
> 2. (hidden)Box shown and not checked: Declined / no
> 3. Box not shown: Not Shown / blank
>
> if the requirements 1/2/3 can be met using a single checkbox .The reason i ask is a single checkbox can hold only one value and if there is a way i can alter the value in Jquery dynamically still satisfying all the requirements.

Yes, it is possible. You can create an object having properties set to selectors `:checked`, `:not(:checked, :hidden)`, `:hidden`; with corresponding values set to `yes`, `no`, `blank`. Set variable at `change` event handler using `for..in` loop, `.is()`

```js
var obj = {
  ":checked": "yes",
  ":not(:checked, :hidden)": "no",
  ":hidden": "blank"
};
var curr;
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if ($(this).is(prop)) {
      curr = obj[prop]; break;
    }
  }
  // do stuff with `curr`
  console.log(curr);
});

// check `:hidden`
$(":checkbox").prop("hidden", true)
.change()  // `curr` should log `blank`
.prop("hidden", false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created one sample onchange function where you can handle mutiple events

codepen URL for reference:
http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xOGNYW

```
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkTest" onchange="myFunction()">

        <input type="text" id="myText" value="checked">



        #myText
        {
          display:none;
        }



              function myFunction() {
                if (document.getElementById("checkTest").checked) {
                  document.getElementById("myText").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                  document.getElementById("myText").style.display = "none";
                }
              }
```